# How can i install software in Google App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to install libmagickwand-dev inside google app engine standard environment

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

is it possible to install a standard environment? or other environments?

package details: [Installation](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in the standard environment, in which you can only use language-specific libraries that can be installed by your language-specific installer (like `pip` for python).

But you can do that in the flexible environment. From [Choosing an App Engine environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments):

> Runs in a Docker container that includes a custom runtime or source
>   code written in other programming languages.

See also [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).